# How to fix Facebook SDK "No getter method for read from property" compile error?

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

I upgrade Facebook Login SDK to version 5.5.0 with Pod, but I got a strange compile error "No getter method for read from property" in FBSDKAppEventsUtility.mm file, It seems that FBSDKSettings.limitEventAndDataUsage property is not defined!

```
parameters[@"application_tracking_enabled"] = @(!FBSDKSettings.limitEventAndDataUsage).stringValue;
```

Anyone have same issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution for this?